# Vaadin 19.0.6 Grid item details stuck when navigating back to view with @UIScope

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have a view with single select grid, which has custom item details renderer. View has @UIScope annotation.

There is an issue with details opening\closing. To reproduce it you have to leave the view and then return back to it (No matter how. Navigating with browser back button or with vaadin router).

First case when setDetailsVisibleOnClick(true) then you could end up having details opened or closed. For example, first time I navigate back the details were opened. Then I repeat navigating from and back to view and the details were closed this time.

Second case when I have setDetailsVisibleOnClick(false) and implement click listener with setDetailsVisible for the item. Also I am setting selectedItem variable add then select(selectedItem) and setDetailsVisible(selectedItem,true) in onAttach method.
Now when I navigate back to view the item is selected and details opened. However, when I select other item the remembered item details remain opened.
Actually, this is also true for the first case with setDetailsVisibleOnClick(true). If you return to view and the details are opened then they stay opened after you click on other grid item.

```
   @Override
    public void onAttach(AttachEvent event) {
        //https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid/issues/1850
        setDetailsVisibleOnClick(true);
        setDetailsVisibleOnClick(false);
        if (selectedItem != null) {
            select(selectedItem);
            if (detailsRenderer != null) setDetailsVisible(selectedItem, true);
            scrollToIndex(dataProvider.getItems().indexOf(selectedItem));
        }
    }
```

and SingleSelectionListener

```
event -> {
            var item = event.getSelectedItem().orElse(null);
            if (detailsRenderer != null) {
                var oldVal = event.getOldValue();
                if (selectedItem != null) setDetailsVisible(selectedItem, false);
                if (oldVal != null) setDetailsVisible(oldVal, false);
                if (item != null) setDetailsVisible(item, true);
                getElement().executeJs("this.notifyResize()");//preserve rows heights on grid container resize
            }
            selectedItem = event.getSelectedItem().orElse(null);
        }
```

Comment: Could you check this ticket from Vaadin's Grid issue tracker and compare if your problem root cause is actually the same https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid/issues/1850

Comment: No, this is different issue. I have specially marked workaround for issue 1850 in onAttach code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to workaround it like this. In my Grid extended class:

```
    public void restoreSavedSelection() {
        var items = dataProvider.getItems();
        if (selectedItem != null && !items.isEmpty() && items.contains(selectedItem)) {
            var index = items.indexOf(selectedItem);//workaround
            select(items.get(index));
            scrollToIndex(index);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void scrollToIndex(int rowIndex) {
        getElement().executeJs("setTimeout(function() { $0.scrollToIndex($1) })", getElement(), rowIndex);
    }
```